# javascript validation for length with spaces

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

I have a functionality which calculates the length of the characters in text area as follows:
JSP code:

```
<textarea class="textAreaLarge" id="citation" rows="20" cols="180" name="citation" maxlength="<%=maxCitationLength%>" onKeyUp="toCount(<%=maxCitationLength%>);"><%=citation%></textarea>
            <strong><div id="sBann" class="minitext"></div></strong>
```

JS is

```
function toCount(){
document.getElementById('citation').onkeyup = function () {
  document.getElementById('sBann').innerHTML = (characters - this.value.length) + " characters left.";
};
}
```

Say for example this is the content of the text area ignoring the quotes. This is a total of 10 characters excluding the quotes.

```
"test

1111"
```

javascript does it correctly. Say MaxLength is 1500 it says '1490 characters left'.

When the same validation is done again on the java side this is what the code does.

```
int maxCitationLength = utility.getMaxCitationLength(rec);
String txtCitation = myUtil.checkNull(citationForm.getValue("citation"));
if (txtCitation.length() > maxCitationLength) {
    request.setAttribute("error",
                         "The Citation field cannot be larger than " + maxCitationLength +
                         " characters.");
}
```

There is always a discrepancy between these 2 conditions. For example I typed 1500 characters including spaces in text area and the form says 0 characters left and doesnt let me type more. But when I submit servlet does the validation again and gets error saying field cannot be larger than 1500 characters.Constant value is same 1500. However I guess the space is calculated differently in java and javascript. What is the best way to do this? ANy suggestions please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, Spring MVC will convert `LF = Line Feed, CR = carriage return` to `\r \n`. I tried to reproduce on my code.

[image: Text area in form]
[image: Request param]

So that my solution is that we will replace these characters with a `space`.

With Javascript:

`someText = someText.replace(/(\n|\r)/g, " ");`

With Java:

`str = str.replaceAll(/(\n|\r)/g, " ")`

Comment: thank you. I tried to include the same in javascript because JS doesnt calculate the \r, \n.But still they wouldnt match. Is there any list that contains all the special characters? Because its a text area and any specil characters would be used including brackets and anything.

Comment: Sorry for unclear answer, i just tried to include example an answer to solve this type of problem. From what you said, the JS validation (toCount() function) is doing its job well. The problem is that browser will convert these new line, space to UTF-8 (you can check this on param section of request in Network tab), and in backend these params will be convert to \r \n. Your job is to replace these with Java code to match with client side. You can run as debug mode or log that String to inspect the result.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I figured that out and it works now.